# How to get 15 minutes time intervals for given duration pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input data frame df

```
start_time end_time
  10:15     11:30
  14:30     15:15
  02:00     03:15
```

Expect output

```
Time_Intervals
[10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:15, 11:30]
[14:30, 14:45, 15:00, 15:15]
[02:00, 02:15, 02:30, 02:45, 03:00, 03:15]
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for gettig value from `'start_time' and 'end_time'`, [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) and `strftime('%H:%M')` for getting like `Hour:Min`. By thanks [DarrylG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3066077/darrylg) you can try like below.

```
df['Time_Intervals'] = df.apply(
    lambda row : pd.date_range(
        row['start_time'], row['end_time'], freq='15T'
    ).strftime("%H:%M").tolist(), axis=1)

print(df)
```

---

```
  start_time end_time                              Time_Intervals
0      10:15    11:30  [10:15, 10:30, 10:45, 11:00, 11:15, 11:30]
1      14:30    15:15                [14:30, 14:45, 15:00, 15:15]
2       2:00     3:15  [02:00, 02:15, 02:30, 02:45, 03:00, 03:15]
```

Explanation, *How convert `DatetimeIndex` to desired format?*

```
# Explanation
lst = pd.date_range('14:30', '15:15', freq='15T').strftime("%H:%M").tolist()
print(lst)
# ['14:30', '14:45', '15:00', '15:15']
```

Comment: You can avoid looping with: `lambda row: pd.date_range(row['start_time'], row['end_time'], freq = '15T').strftime("%H:%M").tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [date_range](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html)

```
pandas.date_range("10:15", "11:30", freq="15min")
```

You can use `apply` and and write a custom preprocessing function like this.

```
def time_intervals(start, end):
    # credits DerrylG
    return pd.date_range(
        start, end, freq="15min"
    ).strftime("%H:%M").tolist()

df["time_intervals"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: time_intervals(x.start_time, x.end_time), axis=1
)
```

Comment: I'm getting output as DatetimeIndex. How to get only time?

Comment: Added edit. Now it should work as expected.